# How to display particular rows from JSON data in Ionic 4

Tags: json, pipe, ionic4

I have two JSON data given below:

userMcData:

```
[
   {
      "MACHINE_ID":4,
      "MCNAME":“RF21”
   },
   {
      "MACHINE_ID":5,
      "MCNAME":“RF22”
   },
   {
      "MACHINE_ID":6,
      "MCNAME":“RF23”
   }
]
```

**userMcData** JSON shows the Machine ID and Machine Name.

items:

```
[
   {
      "Mcname":“RF21”,
      "Side":"L",
      "Breaks":101,
      “1”:20,
      “2”:10,
      “3”:15,
      “4”:11,
      “5”:9,
      “6”:10,
      “7”:6,
      “8”:8,
      “9”:12,
      “10”:0,
      “11”:0,
      “12”:0,
      “13”:0,
      “14”:0
   },
   {
      "Mcname":“RF21”,
      "Side":"R",
      "Breaks":94,
      “1”:18,
      “2”:11,
      “3”:11,
      “4”:3,
      “5”:11,
      “6”:18,
      “7”:10,
      “8”:5,
      “9”:7,
      “10”:0,
      “11”:0,
      “12”:0,
      “13”:0,
      “14”:0
   },
   {
      "Mcname":“RF22”,
      "Side":"L",
      "Breaks":151,
      “1”:12,
      “2”:13,
      “3”:13,
      “4”:25,
      “5”:15,
      “6”:12,
      “7”:29,
      “8”:17,
      “9”:15,
      “10”:0,
      “11”:0,
      “12”:0,
      “13”:0,
      “14”:0
   },
   {
      "Mcname":“RF22”,
      "Side":"R",
      "Breaks":316,
      “1”:51,
      “2”:27,
      “3”:23,
      “4”:26,
      “5”:28,
      “6”:57,
      “7”:39,
      “8”:41,
      “9”:24,
      “10”:0,
      “11”:0,
      “12”:0,
      “13”:0,
      “14”:0
   },
   {
      "Mcname":“RF23”,
      "Side":"L",
      "Breaks":164,
      “1”:15,
      “2”:22,
      “3”:19,
      “4”:14,
      “5”:13,
      “6”:20,
      “7”:15,
      “8”:22,
      “9”:24,
      “10”:0,
      “11”:0,
      “12”:0,
      “13”:0,
      “14”:0
   },
   {
      "Mcname":“RF23”,
      "Side":"R",
      "Breaks":0,
      “1”:0,
      “2”:0,
      “3”:0,
      “4”:0,
      “5”:0,
      “6”:0,
      “7”:0,
      “8”:0,
      “9”:0,
      “10”:0,
      “11”:0,
      “12”:0,
      “13”:0,
      “14”:0
   }
]
```

**items** JSON shows the Machine ID,Side,and some more columns. In this JSON, each Machine must have 2 rows.

Both the JSON data are dynamic.

I want to show this data as given below:

[image: Image1]

I want to show the data as Cards for each Machine from **userMcData** JSON. In each card, I have to show the particular machine data from the **items** JSON. I have tried with pipe. And the above image is taken from modified **items** JSON.

code:

```
keys.pipe.ts:

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'keys'
})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {
    return Object.keys(value);
  }
}
```

HTML Code:

```html
<ion-card *ngFor="let machine of userMcData">
    <ion-card-header>
      <div>
          <span class="alignleft">{{machine.MCNAME}}</span>
        </div>
   </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row *ngFor="let item of items">
          <ion-col *ngFor="let list of item | keys">
            {{item[list]}}
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: You can make array with each element contains 2 objects for left right and third for Mac info. Then send to html. Here you can simply display on screen.

Comment: Did you have any tutorial link for that? Seriously I am new to this, And  don't know how to do that.

Comment: I have worked in ionic longed time ago. let me search. I suggest to start with simple flow. then make it complex. Like send send simple variable to view from controller and show it. Then Array and display it.so on.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `keyvalue` pipe offered by the angular. By default it sorts the result by the key. So had to use a compare function to retain the original order.

So the HTML Code will look like -

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let machine of userMcData">
  <ion-card-header>
    <div>
      <span class="alignleft">{{machine.MCNAME}}</span>
    </div>
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>
    <ion-grid>
      <ion-row *ngFor="let item of items">
        <ng-container *ngIf="item.Mcname === machine.MCNAME">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let list of item | keyvalue: originalOrder">
            <ng-container *ngIf="!(list.key === 'Mcname' ||
                                  list.key === 'Side' ||
                                  list.key === 'Breaks')">
              <ion-col>
                {{list.value}}
              </ion-col>
            </ng-container>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

And add the compare function to the TS file -

```
originalOrder = (a: KeyValue<number, string>, b: KeyValue<number, string>): number => {
    return 0;
  }
```

Here is the Output -

[image: Output image]

Comment: Thanks @arif08 for your great reply. I don't know where to paste the code in TS file. While pasting the text it shows error in KeyValue word. Kindly explain me a little bit. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Wow Thanks @arif08. Now I have used the keyvalue method. Thank u so much. Really its very helpful.

Comment: @PrasanthPFA appreciate it.
Although I want to include that, judging from you JSON data you might want to make sure that the value is displayed correctly all the time. Here I haven't sorted the data rather kept it as is using the `originatOrder` method. You might want to work here and sort the keys.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below logic, structuring might change according to how you want to display:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let machine of userMcData">
    <ion-card-header>
      <div>
          <span class="alignleft">{{machine.MCNAME}}</span>
        </div>
   </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-grid>
        <ion-row *ngFor="let item of items">
          <ion-col *ngIf="item.Mcname == machine.MCNAME">
            <span *ngFor="let item_data in Object.keys(item)" *ngIf="item_data!='Mcname' && item_data!='Side' && item_data!='Breaks'">{{ item[item_data] }}></span>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </ion-grid>
    </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used the same and got the error.                                   ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute prefixed with * ("="item.Mcname == machine.MCNAME">
                <span *ngFor="let item_data in Object.keys(item)" [ERROR ->]*ngIf="item_data!='Mcname'">{{ item[item_data] }}></span>
              </ion-col>
            </ion-"): ng:///HomescreenPageModule/HomescreenPage.html@19:66

Comment: I have tried and changed something. Now I got this error:  **Can't bind to 'ngForIn' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.**